# Is the term "you only live once" accepted?

Tags: word-choice

Technically, you live everyday but you only die once. So in this case shouldn't it be you only die once? Is you only live once correct?

Comment: YOLO!!!     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YOLO_(motto)

Comment: This is more a question of logic than about the English language. Obviously the term is *accepted*. you are asking whether it makes sense. Suggest asking at Philosophy.SE.

Comment: You only live once? [Tell that to James Bond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062512/).

Answer (score 2):

Why would it not be correct? Each day is not a separate life, but part of a single continuous life.  You only get one.  It could hypothetically be possible to live twice, but die once, if you were reincarnated to an immortal being.  That doesn't happen, so *you only live once*.

Comment: You only live twice or so it seems: one life for yourself and one for your dreams. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be *you only die once.* When you say *you only live once,* it means that *you've only got one lifetime, so why not take a risk?*

When putting your life at risk (or taking any risk), you wouldn't say *you only die once,* for a number of reasons. First, that suggests you want or are planning to die, when in fact the goal is to survive. And second, you cannot come back from death, so to say *you only die once* suggests finality.